# Zero-inflated Poisson - Implementing INLA with two likelihoods

Tags: r, mixed-model, likelihood, zero-inflation, inla

I am trying to implement a zero inflated model in INLA.
I know a basic zero inflated Poisson can be implemented with `"zeroinflatedpoisson1"` as the family argument as described [here](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/suppl/2017/05/01/132753.DC1/132753-3.pdf) (where I also took the example below). However, [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/1660-4601/16/22/4460) describes a different approach where the two likelihoods are written into the INLA call, and the response is an matrix with $2n$ rows and 2 columns corresponding to the likelihoods.

I have tried to implement it below with the Owls data from `glmmTMB`, but the results suggest it has not implemented two likelihoods. However, the results are close, but different, from the Poisson version shown at the end.

```r
library(INLA)
library(tidyverse)

df <- glmmTMB::Owls |> mutate(NCalls= SiblingNegotiation)

df1 <- df |> mutate(ziy = ifelse(NCalls == 0, 0 , 1), 
                    NCalls = NA)
df$ziy <- NA
dff <- rbind(df1,df)

dff$Y <- data.frame(dff[, c("ziy", "NCalls")]) 

# zip model - doesnt seem to work

m.zip <- inla(Y~ FoodTreatment + ArrivalTime + SexParent +
                       logBroodSize + f(Nest, model = "iid"), 
                     family= c("binomial", "poisson"),
                     data=dff,
                     control.fixed=list(mean=0, prec = 1),
                     control.predictor=list(compute=TRUE),
                     control.compute=list(dic=TRUE, cpo=TRUE, waic=TRUE))

summary(m.zip)

# Call:
#   c("inla.core(formula = formula, family = family, contrasts = contrasts, ", " data = data, 
#    quantiles = quantiles, E = E, offset = offset, ", " scale = scale, weights = weights, Ntrials 
#    = Ntrials, strata = strata, ", " lp.scale = lp.scale, link.covariates = link.covariates, 
#    verbose = verbose, ", " lincomb = lincomb, selection = selection, control.compute = 
#    control.compute, ", " control.predictor = control.predictor, control.family = control.family, 
#    ", " control.inla = control.inla, control.fixed = control.fixed, ", " control.mode = 
#    control.mode, control.expert = control.expert, ", " control.hazard = control.hazard, 
#    control.lincomb = control.lincomb, ", " control.update = control.update, control.lp.scale = 
#    control.lp.scale, ", " control.pardiso = control.pardiso, only.hyperparam = only.hyperparam, 
#    ", " inla.call = inla.call, inla.arg = inla.arg, num.threads = num.threads, ", " 
#    blas.num.threads = blas.num.threads, keep = keep, working.directory = working.directory, ", " 
#    silent = silent, inla.mode = inla.mode, safe = FALSE, debug = debug, ", " .parent.frame = 
#    .parent.frame)") 
# Time used:
#   Pre = 2.82, Running = 0.42, Post = 0.0163, Total = 3.26 
# Fixed effects:
#   mean    sd 0.025quant 0.5quant 0.975quant   mode kld
# (Intercept)            4.549 0.404      3.759    4.547      5.350  4.544   0
# FoodTreatmentSatiated -0.634 0.036     -0.705   -0.634     -0.564 -0.634   0
# ArrivalTime           -0.134 0.009     -0.153   -0.134     -0.116 -0.134   0
# SexParentMale          0.049 0.036     -0.022    0.049      0.119  0.049   0
# logBroodSize           0.518 0.238      0.041    0.521      0.981  0.526   0
# 
# Random effects:
#   Name      Model
# Nest IID model
# 
# Model hyperparameters:
#   mean   sd 0.025quant 0.5quant 0.975quant mode
# Precision for Nest 4.75 1.60       2.24     4.54       8.46 4.13
# 
# Deviance Information Criterion (DIC) ...............: 5564.07
# Deviance Information Criterion (DIC, saturated) ....: 3883.28
# Effective number of parameters .....................: 28.46
# 
# Watanabe-Akaike information criterion (WAIC) ...: 5685.81
# Effective number of parameters .................: 140.35
# 
# Marginal log-Likelihood:  -2833.00 
# CPO, PIT is computed 
# Posterior summaries for the linear predictor and the fitted values are computed
# (Posterior marginals needs also 'control.compute=list(return.marginals.predictor=TRUE)')


# Poisson 
m.p <- inla(NCalls ~ FoodTreatment + ArrivalTime + SexParent +
                       logBroodSize + f(Nest, model = "iid"), 
                     family= c("poisson"),
                     data=df,
                     control.fixed=list(mean=0, prec = 1),
                     control.predictor=list(compute=TRUE),
                     control.compute=list(dic=TRUE, cpo=TRUE, waic=TRUE))
summary(m.p)

# Call:
#   c("inla.core(formula = formula, family = family, contrasts = contrasts, ", " data = data, 
#    quantiles = quantiles, E = E, offset = offset, ", " scale = scale, weights = weights, Ntrials 
#    = Ntrials, strata = strata, ", " lp.scale = lp.scale, link.covariates = link.covariates, 
#    verbose = verbose, ", " lincomb = lincomb, selection = selection, control.compute = 
#    control.compute, ", " control.predictor = control.predictor, control.family = control.family, 
#    ", " control.inla = control.inla, control.fixed = control.fixed, ", " control.mode = 
#    control.mode, control.expert = control.expert, ", " control.hazard = control.hazard, 
#    control.lincomb = control.lincomb, ", " control.update = control.update, control.lp.scale = 
#    control.lp.scale, ", " control.pardiso = control.pardiso, only.hyperparam = only.hyperparam, 
#    ", " inla.call = inla.call, inla.arg = inla.arg, num.threads = num.threads, ", " 
#    blas.num.threads = blas.num.threads, keep = keep, working.directory = working.directory, ", " 
#    silent = silent, inla.mode = inla.mode, safe = FALSE, debug = debug, ", " .parent.frame = 
#    .parent.frame)") 
# Time used:
#   Pre = 2.86, Running = 0.379, Post = 0.0433, Total = 3.28 
# Fixed effects:
#   mean    sd 0.025quant 0.5quant 0.975quant   mode kld
# (Intercept)            4.457 0.383      3.707    4.455      5.215  4.452   0
# FoodTreatmentSatiated -0.585 0.036     -0.656   -0.585     -0.515 -0.585   0
# ArrivalTime           -0.130 0.009     -0.148   -0.130     -0.111 -0.130   0
# SexParentMale          0.042 0.036     -0.029    0.042      0.113  0.042   0
# logBroodSize           0.511 0.219      0.072    0.513      0.936  0.518   0
# 
# Random effects:
#   Name      Model
# Nest IID model
# 
# Model hyperparameters:
#   mean   sd 0.025quant 0.5quant 0.975quant mode
# Precision for Nest 5.92 2.01       2.77     5.65      10.57 5.14
# 
# Deviance Information Criterion (DIC) ...............: 4945.64
# Deviance Information Criterion (DIC, saturated) ....: 3264.82
# Effective number of parameters .....................: 28.40
# 
# Watanabe-Akaike information criterion (WAIC) ...: 5060.26
# Effective number of parameters .................: 135.53
# 
# Marginal log-Likelihood:  -2520.86 
# CPO, PIT is computed 
# Posterior summaries for the linear predictor and the fitted values are computed
# (Posterior marginals needs also 'control.compute=list(return.marginals.predictor=TRUE)')
#
```